# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody' - Spyder 3.3.1 / beautifulsoup4 / python 3.6

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, spyder, attributeerror

Hey this is my setup: Spyder 3.3.1 / beautifulsoup4 / python 3.6

The below code is from an article on medium ([here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-short-practical-how-to-guide-to-scrape-data-from-a-website-using-python-888373227d4f)) about webscraping with python and Beautifulsoup. Was supposed to be a quick read but now TWO days later I still cant not get the code to run in spyder and keep getting:

```
File "/Users/xxxxxxx/Documents/testdir/swiftScrape.py", line 9, in table_to_df
    return pd.DataFrame([[td.text for td in row.findAll('td')] for row in table.tbody.findAll('tr')])

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'
```

Not sure what is going wrong and seems to be an implementation error. Can anyone assist in sheding some light on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
import os
import bs4
import requests
import pandas as pd

PATH = os.path.join("C:\\","Users","xxxxx","Documents","tesdir")

def table_to_df(table):
    return pd.DataFrame([[td.text for td in row.findAll('td')] for row in table.tbody.findAll('tr')])

def next_page(soup):
    return "http:" + soup.find('a', attrs={'rel':'next'}).get('href')

res = pd.DataFrame()
url = "http://bank-code.net/country/FRANCE-%28FR%29/"
counter = 0

while True:
    print(counter)
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find(name='table', attrs={'id':'tableID'})
    res = res.append(table_to_df(table))
    res.to_csv(os.path.join(PATH,"BIC","table.csv"), index=None, sep=';', encoding='iso-8859-1')
    url = next_page(soup)
    counter += 1
```

Comment: did you at least searched about this error ? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NoneType+has+no+attribute

Comment: yes and also for alternative syntax for `'table'` and the return query in `table_to_df` in beautifulsoup documentation but didn't come up with a solution to my particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @bruno desthuilliers for your pointers. Much appreciated.

This is the rewritten code that worked for me using Selenium and webdriver rather than `import requests`:

```
import os
import bs4
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = os.path.join('/','Users','benmorris','documents','testdir')

def table_to_df(table):
    return pd.DataFrame([[td.text for td in row.find_all('td')] for row in soup.find_all('tr')])

def next_page(soup):
    return "http:" + soup.find('a', attrs={'rel':'next'}).get('href')

res = pd.DataFrame()
url = "http://bank-code.net/country/FRANCE-%28FR%29/"
counter = 0
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

while True:
    print(counter)
    page = driver.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tableID"]')
    if table is None:
        print("no table 'tableID' found for url {}".format(url))
        print("html content:\n{}\n".format( page.content))
        continue
    res = res.append(table_to_df(table))
    res.to_csv(os.path.join(PATH,"BIC","table.csv"), index=False, sep=',', encoding='iso-8859-1')
    url = next_page(soup)
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like a lost of example code found on the web, this code is not production-grade code - it blindly assumes that http requests always succeed and returns the expected content. The truth is that it's quite often not the case (network errors, proxies or firewall that blocks you, site down - temporarily or definitely, updates in the site that changed either the urls and/or the page's markup etc).

Your problem manifests itself here:

```
def table_to_df(table):
    return pd.DataFrame([[td.text for td in row.findAll('td')] for row in table.tbody.findAll('tr')])
```

and comes from `table` actually being `None`, which means that here in the for loop:

```
table = soup.find(name='table', attrs={'id':'tableID'})
```

there was no "table" tag with id "tableID" found in the html document. You can check this by printing the actual html content:

```
while True:
    print(counter)
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find(name='table', attrs={'id':'tableID'})
    if table is None:
        print("no table 'tableID' found for url {}".format(url))
        print("html content:\n{}\n".format( page.content))
        continye

    # etc
```

Comment: I see. The tag `table` with `ID: tableID` exists in the tree as:

    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tableID" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">

Comment: So..... must be a request issue. I'll research what factors have an impact on the https request getting through. Any steer on best practise troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: "must be a request issue" => as I said, the issue here is that the html content (`page.content`) doesn't match the code expectations. Check the response's  (what is named "page" in this code snippet) status code (should be 200), check the html content itself (cf my answer), check what you get if you load the same url in your browser, etc...